# awk split by sequence of whitespaces

Tags: regex, awk, split, whitespace, separator

Can `split(string, array, separator)` in **awk**  use sequence of whitespaces as the separator (or more generally any regexp as the separator)?

Obviously, one could use the internal autosplit (that runs on each line of the input with value of `FS` variable as the separator) and with simple `for` and `$0` magic do the trick. However, I was just wondering if there's a more straightforward way using the `split`itself.

Comment: Can you tell us what task you are trying to accomplish, and provide some input/out sample(s). There might be alternatives to split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) states:

```
split(string, array, fieldsep)
```

> This divides string into pieces separated by fieldsep, and stores the
>   pieces in  array. The first piece is stored in array[1], the second
>   piece in array[2], and  so forth. The string value of the third
>   argument, ***fieldsep, is a regexp*** describing where to split string (much
>   as FS can be a regexp describing where to split input  records). If
>   the fieldsep is omitted, the value of FS is used. split returns the 
>   number of elements created. The split function, then, splits strings
>   into pieces  in a manner similar to the way input lines are split into
>   fields

Here is a short (somewhat silly) example that uses a simple *regular expression* `".s "` that will match any single character followed by a lower-case `s` and a space. The result of the split is put into array `a`. Note that the parts that match are *not* placed into the array.

```
BEGIN { 
  s = "this isn't a string yes isodore?"
  count = split(s, a, ".s ")
  printf("number of splits: %d\n", count)

  print "Contents of array:"
  for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
    printf "a[%d]: %s\n", i, a[i]
}
```

The output:

```
$ awk -f so.awk

number of splits: 3
Contents of array:
a[1]: th
a[2]: isn't a string y
a[3]: isodore?
```

The article [Advanced Awk for Sysadmins](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/advanced-awk-for-sysadmins/) show an example of parsing a line using `split()`. This [page](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/31140-regular-expression-query-awk.html) contains an example of using a regular expression to split data into
an array.

Answer (score 2):

From the GNU awk(1) manual page:

```
split(s, a [, r])
```

> Splits the string s into the array a on the regular expression r, and returns the number of fields. If r is omitted, FS is used instead.

The point here is that you can use any regular expression to perform field splitting--at least you can with gawk. If you're using something else, you'll need to check your documentation.

Comment: The GNU Extensions section of the `man` page only refers to using a null string to split individual characters. Using regular expressions in general with `FS` and `split()` is not an extension.